# How to use sed to extract a matching pattern from a text file?

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to extract the element contained in version by using sed. I have a pattern that matches all elements like it (`[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{1}`), but I just need the first match.

The objective would be to be able to output the match, and just the match - without the quotes - to standard output.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.company.application" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
...`

I h

Comment: don't parse xml with sed, use xml parsers. I  can help if you posted a valid xml structure

Comment: [Here you go](https://pastebin.com/raw/9JAF1LZ1). This should be able to be done with Bash/SH/equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex to parse `xml`, use a xml parser, [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) for example, which is bundled on most linux/mac, i.e.:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//*[local-name()="widget"]/@version)' xmlfile
# 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using [***xmlstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) tool:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '_:widget' -v "@version" -n xmlfile
```

The output:

```
1.0.0
```

---

`-v "@version"` - get value of `version` attribute